# Can you patent an existing bacteria without any modifications?

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US7244424](https://www.google.com/patents/US7244424)

Comment: Another related question can be found here: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/14278/can-bacteria-be-patented

Answer (score 2):

You can not patent something that is naturally created. You could patent processes or equipment that is used to raise such. It can not be obvious or described in prior art. You need to demonstrate innovation.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I was looking at US7244424 which seems to be a patent on a specific genus, species and strain of probiotic bacteria. L. fermentum - how is this possible?

Comment: Look at the claims! They claim a process to get the strain. They are not claiming the strain.